# PivotChart - ActiveChart.Refresh works only when debugging

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, pivot-table

I have an Excel workbook in which I am generating a pivot chart per VBA from an existing pivot table. This chart is created as a new worksheet.

So far the result is as expected. But when I go to the generated chart and want to change something in the field editor I get an error message:

> Pivot table report was saved without the underlying source data. Select "Refresh data", to refresh the report. *(Translated from German)*

After doing so, I can work in the field editor. After a long nerve-wracking debugging session I figured out, that my code behaves differently when stepping through it with the debugger.

- When executing the code normally, .Refresh has seemingly no effect.
- When stepping through the code with the debugger, .Refresh works just as expected and I don't get an error message in the field editor.

I tried it with Excel 2010 and 2013. Both versions show the same behavior.

```
  Charts.Add    
  chartSheetName = dqSource & "_PIVOT_CHART"
  With ActiveChart
    .Location where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet , Name:=chartSheetName 
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Select
    .ChartTitle.Text = "My chart title"  
    .Refresh ' <-- This is the suspect
  End With
```

Comment: Is there any sheet in the workbook that is protected?

Comment: Nope, no protected sheets or other fancy stuff.

Answer (score 5):

The `PivotChart` depends on a `PivotTable`.

I suggest to refresh the `PivotCache` of that pivottable instead:

```
With myPivotTable
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the line of code:

```
Do Events
```

after this to initiate the code in a real time run.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the solution. It had no effect on my workbook.

Comment: what about ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll on a new line instead of the with activechart.refresh line

Answer (score 0):

your problem is caused because you need to link the underlying data within the worksheet.
being positioning in pivot table's cell, Go to pivot table options=> data tab => check the option "save source data with file". This option makes excel to save the pivotcache with the worksheet.

I hope that this help you.
Best regards from Colombia.

Comment: Unfortunately it helped not. I have to Refresh the workbook in the Workbook_Open() event.